# C++ for loop and range-based loop performance

Tags: c++, c++11, for-loop

I read that range-based loops have better performance on some programming language. Is it the case in C++.
For instance;

```
int main()
{
    vector<int> v = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

    auto size = v.size();
    // LOOP1
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        // do something with v[i]
    }

    // LOOP2    
    for (int& val : v) {
        // do something with val 
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Does `LOOP2` perform better than `LOOP1` when `vector` size is huge? If so, why?

Comment: Not a fair comparison. You're making copies of all of the elements in the second version. If that was fixed, the difference should be negligible, if existent. Testing them appropriately would tell you better than I could.

Comment: The optimizer has to do a bit more work to optimize the first loop, but this has to do with the kind of iteration you use here. For some (older) compilers, iterating with iterators can be more efficient. I have tested this some time ago using VS2010 and matrix containers.

Comment: This seems like something that you could benchmark. I would hope the loop with `int& val` optimizes at least as well as the other loop. If you find out differently, maybe you could show a working example and the running times for the two loops and ask why it is so.

Comment: I once heard Andrei Alexandrescu say that measuring gives you a leg up over people who are so good they don't need to measure. :)

Comment: range-for is syntactic sugar for iterators. So you are really comparing using an index vs using an iterator, and I am sure there are older posts on SO doing just that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a crude test. I'm not saying this is a definitive answer as to which is faster, but it seems to me in this particular case, the gcc compiler is able to optimize both loops to roughly the same performance level. You can definitely improve on the testing method, if you wish.

On my system (Ubuntu 14.04, some sort of i7, 8 GB DDR3, gcc):

Without optimization (g++ main.cpp -std=c++11):

> Old-fashioned loop: 5.45131 seconds.
>
> Range-based loop: 9.90306 seconds.

With optimization (g++ main.cpp -O3 -std=c++11):

> Old-fashioned loop: 0.469001 seconds.
>
> Range-based loop: 0.467045 seconds.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <time.h>
using namespace std;

double time_elapsed(timespec& start, timespec& end)
{
    return ((1e9 * end.tv_sec + end.tv_nsec) - 
            (1e9 * start.tv_sec + start.tv_nsec)) / 1.0e9;
}

int main()
{
    vector<int> v(1e9, 42);

    timespec start, end;

//  Old-fashioned loop.
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW, &start);
    size_t size = v.size();
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        v[i] *= v[i];
    }
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW, &end);

    cout << "Old-fashioned loop: " << time_elapsed(start, end) << " seconds\n";

//  Range-based loop.
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW, &start); 
    for (int& val : v)
    {
        val *= val;
    }
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW, &end);

    cout << "Range-based loop: " << time_elapsed(start, end) << " seconds.\n";
}
```

Comment: What compiler settings did you use to compile this?

Comment: Micro-benchmarking is *really* complicated. At the very least, you need to post the compiler version and compilation settings. Then, retry the program with inverted loops, or even better, only one loop. Or use a proper framework. Also, you have to make sure that you produce *visible* side effects. There are much more problems.

Comment: @dyp I don't mean this to be a canonical answer about which type of loop is faster, but the OP can run a similar test on their particular scenario. Or a more complex test depending on their needs. Of course I wouldn't say one is faster than the other given these numbers, if anything I'd say the compiler seems to be smart enough to optimize them both to roughly the same level. In this case I'd go with the range-based loop because it's more readable.

Comment: I still think you cannot really conclude that from the code you've shown. But I think it's somewhat acceptable with the disclaimer. Removed downvote.

Answer (score 6):

I tested them both using the following code:

```
#include <benchmark/benchmark.h>
#include <vector>

auto get_vector(int size) {
    return std::vector<int>(size, 2333);
}
template <class F>
void BM_for_range(benchmark::State &state)
{
    for(auto _: state) {
        state.PauseTiming();

        F{}(get_vector(state.range(0)), state);//Run the test
    }
}
struct v1 {
    template <class T>
    void operator () (std::vector<T> v, benchmark::State &state) {
        state.ResumeTiming();

        auto size = v.size();
        decltype(size) i = 0;
        for (; i != size; i++) {
            v[i] *= v[i];
        }
    }
};
struct v2 {
    template <class T>
    void operator () (std::vector<T> v, benchmark::State &state) {
        state.ResumeTiming();

        for (int& val : v) {
            val *= val;
        }
    }
};

BENCHMARK_TEMPLATE(BM_for_range, v1)->Range(64, (1 << 30));
BENCHMARK_TEMPLATE(BM_for_range, v2)->Range(64, (1 << 30));
BENCHMARK_MAIN();
```

All the performance test are done on:

```
Debian 9.4, Linux version 4.9.0-6-amd64 (debian-kernel@lists.debian.org)(gcc version 6.3.0 20170516 (Debian 6.3.0-18+deb9u1) ) #1 SMP Debian 4.9.82-1+deb9u3 (2018-03-02)
```

Compiled using `clang++-6.0 -std=c++17 -lbenchmark -lpthread -Ofast main.cc`

And got the result from running these in bash:

```
sudo cpupower frequency-set --governor performance
./a.out
```

Result:

```
Run on (8 X 1600 MHz CPU s)
CPU Caches:
  L1 Data 32K (x4)
  L1 Instruction 32K (x4)
  L2 Unified 256K (x4)
  L3 Unified 6144K (x1)
-------------------------------------------------------------------
Benchmark                            Time           CPU Iterations
-------------------------------------------------------------------
BM_for_range<v1>/64                929 ns        932 ns     763881
BM_for_range<v1>/512              1051 ns       1053 ns     662887
BM_for_range<v1>/4096             2195 ns       2199 ns     317788
BM_for_range<v1>/32768           12484 ns      12509 ns      57699
BM_for_range<v1>/262144         114788 ns     114784 ns       6277
BM_for_range<v1>/2097152       1270037 ns    1269506 ns        554
BM_for_range<v1>/16777216     16472508 ns   16468972 ns         43
BM_for_range<v1>/134217728   130165013 ns  130136049 ns          5
BM_for_range<v1>/1073741824  986169581 ns  986168129 ns          1
BM_for_range<v2>/64                925 ns        927 ns     730624
BM_for_range<v2>/512              1060 ns       1062 ns     654477
BM_for_range<v2>/4096             2197 ns       2201 ns     319264
BM_for_range<v2>/32768           12288 ns      12314 ns      53352
BM_for_range<v2>/262144         112196 ns     112191 ns       6220
BM_for_range<v2>/2097152       1268441 ns    1267732 ns        553
BM_for_range<v2>/16777216     16627461 ns   16623624 ns         42
BM_for_range<v2>/134217728   127552348 ns  127551465 ns          6
BM_for_range<v2>/1073741824  963751205 ns  963152928 ns          1
```